# I can't install composer on mac os x

Tags: php, macos, composer-php, macports, php-openssl

Following the instructions from this page (link below), I still can't install the composer and I am not sure where I am failing here. Any good eye to spot my error? I am very close I can feel it but no luck yet and it's probably a simple mistake I am doing here... Please help!

https://getcomposer.org/download/

**Step 1:**

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

**Console response:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
```

**Step 2:**

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

**Response:**

```
Apache Version
Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.1e DAV/2 PHP/5.4.15

Additional .ini files parsed
/opt/local/var/db/php54/openssl.ini,

OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

**Step 3:**

```
cd /opt/local/var/db
ls -al
```

**Response:**

```
drwxr-xr-x  25 root    admin    850  6 Jan 23:52 php5
drwxr-xr-x   4 root    admin    136 29 Dec 20:39 php53
drwxr-xr-x  27 root    admin    918 28 Jan 12:34 php54
```

**Step 4:**

```
cd php54
ls -al
```

**Response:**

```
......
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  237 10 May  2013 openssl.ini
......
```

**Step 5:**

```
vim openssl.ini
```

**Response:**

```
; Do not edit this file; it is automatically generated by MacPorts. Any changes
; you make will be lost if you upgrade, uninstall or deactivate php54-openssl.
; To configure php54, edit /opt/local/etc/php54/php.ini.
extension=openssl.so
```

**Step 5: (just to double check)**

```
sudo port install php54-openssl
```

**Response:**

```
--->  Computing dependencies for php54-openssl
--->  Cleaning php54-openssl
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
```

**Step 6:**

```
sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k restart
```

**Step 7:**

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

**Response:**

*As in step 1*

**Step 8:**

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php54
```

**Response:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Could not create file /opt/local/var/db/php54/composer.phar: fopen(/opt/local/var/db/php54/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Download failed: fopen(/opt/local/var/db/php54/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Downloading...
Could not create file /opt/local/var/db/php54/composer.phar: fopen(/opt/local/var/db/php54/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Download failed: fopen(/opt/local/var/db/php54/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Downloading...
Could not create file /opt/local/var/db/php54/composer.phar: fopen(/opt/local/var/db/php54/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Download failed: fopen(/opt/local/var/db/php54/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

**Step 9:**

```
sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php54
```

**Response:**

*As in step 8*

Comment: `step 9` try the `sudo` on the php54 side, `curl`ing shouldn't be the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 9:**

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php54
```

Answer (score 1):

mkdir -p /usr/local/bin

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=1.0.0-alpha11